# Encountering errors when installing a project with Gatsby

Tags: javascript, npm, gatsby

I'm trying to install a project with Gatsby, but I get errors. And so with any project from the official repository.

```
D:\>gatsby new tutorial-part-one https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-hello-world

info Creating new site from git: git+https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-hello-world.git

Cloning into 'tutorial-part-one'...

git: 'remote-git+https' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

> error Command failed: git clone git+https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-hello-world.git tutorial-part-one --single-branch
>
> Error: Command failed: git clone git+https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-hello-world.git tutorial-part-one --si  ngle-branch
>
> - index.js:236 Promise.all.then.arr
>     [npm]/[gatsby-cli]/[execa]/index.js:236:11
> - util.js:16 tryCatcher
>     [npm]/[gatsby-cli]/[bluebird]/js/release/util.js:16:23
> - promise.js:512 Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler
>     [npm]/[gatsby-cli]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:512:31
> - promise.js:569 Promise._settlePromise
>     [npm]/[gatsby-cli]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:569:18
> - promise.js:614 Promise._settlePromise0
>     [npm]/[gatsby-cli]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:614:10
> - promise.js:693 Promise._settlePromises
>     [npm]/[gatsby-cli]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:693:18
> - promise.js:638 Promise._fulfill
>     [npm]/[gatsby-cli]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:638:18
> - promise_array.js:126 PromiseArray._resolve
>     [npm]/[gatsby-cli]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise_array.js:126:19
> - promise_array.js:144 PromiseArray._promiseFulfilled
>     [npm]/[gatsby-cli]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise_array.js:144:14
> - promise.js:574 Promise._settlePromise
>     [npm]/[gatsby-cli]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:574:26
> - promise.js:614 Promise._settlePromise0
>     [npm]/[gatsby-cli]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:614:10
> - promise.js:693 Promise._settlePromises
>     [npm]/[gatsby-cli]/[bluebird]/js/release/promise.js:693:18
> - async.js:133 Async._drainQueue
>     [npm]/[gatsby-cli]/[bluebird]/js/release/async.js:133:16
> - async.js:143 Async._drainQueues
>     [npm]/[gatsby-cli]/[bluebird]/js/release/async.js:143:10
> - async.js:17 Immediate.Async.drainQueues
>     [npm]/[gatsby-cli]/[bluebird]/js/release/async.js:17:14

What could be the problem?